# Javascript Escape Character Replacement

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, insert

I'm using a button to dynamically generate a new table row in my form and the lines include calling functions with parameters. I tried using JQuery on the added lines to trigger the .blur() event, as was successfully done with the hardcoded first table row, but the page completely ignored it. So I'm trying another route of triggering the onblur() event from within the row HTML. I'm getting stuck on the function parameter, as I'm either messing up the escape character order or messing up the translation. I've already spent a few hours on this and tried doing research on Stack Overflow, so I'm hoping a second set of eyes would be able to help.

Here are the relevant pieces of code. The stored html is appended to my table row, which already works.

```
var strVar = 'myString';
var rowCount = $("#tbodyID td").closest("tr").length;
var rowNum = rowCount + 1;


var line17 = "<td><input type='number' class='form-control' name='named_qty' onblur='function(" + strVar + ")' id='row_R" + rowNum.toString() + "' /></td> ";
```

There are approximately 25 lines with varying html to be inserted. I was able to get it to work previously, but realized that a value was hardcoded and I needed it to be dynamic. The function it calls is accepting a string.

When inserted into the HTML document, this line should generally read:

```
<td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="named_qty" onblur="function('myString')" id="row_R2" /></td>
```

Comment: The best practice to do what you are about to do is by using document.createElemenet and the appendchild. This will give you and easier more readable and easy to maintain solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and realized that I was using the JQuery blur() method as :
`$('#id').blur( function() {  });` and trying to call those functions, not realizing that the method only works for HTML elements that had been written to the DOM on page load.

Apparently the solution is to use the JQuery on() method as follows:

```
$(document).on("blur", '#id', function() {   <insert code> });
```

From W3Schools,

> Note: Event handlers attached using the on() method will work for both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script).

This removes the necessity to include the event function call in the HTML line to be appended to the DOM.